# Why is a poset that has a minimum and a maximum *not* a lattice (and a *complete* one at that)?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

This "fact" (see subject line) appears trivial at first glance, yet it doesn't seem to be true (at least I have not been able to find it in any textbook I know). Why is that so? Is there something more subtle about this, or is it that the proof as to why a **poset with top and bottom** is *not* a lattice is trivial and I just can't see it?

Comment: What "fact" do you mean? The title is about something *not* being a lattice.

Comment: Here's the "fact": a(ny) poset with top and bottom is a complete lattice.

Comment: Look at pic 7 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#:~:text=In%20particular%20the%20two%2Delement,2%2C%203%2C%206%7D.)  Isn't this an example?

Comment: Well, it is true that *sometimes* a poset with a minimum and maximum value is not a lattice. To prove this, all you have to do is find one such poset.

Comment: Every finite linear order is poset with a maximum and a minimum element that **is** a complete lattice; the poset shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#/media/File:NoLatticeDiagram.svg) has a maximum and a minimum element but is **not** a lattice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: as drawn, that diagram is not a poset (yes, I understand that it may be customary to omit some non-necessary edges to keep the figure clean). Nevertheless, once I drew up all the requisite edges, it emerged clearly that the set of upper bounds of {b, c} (UB[{b, c}] = {d, e, f}) does *not* have a _least_ element. Many thanks!

Comment: @Aqualung: You’re welcome. (But note that the Hasse diagram of a poset includes only the lines between an element and the elements that cover it, so that most certainly is the Hasse diagram of a poset.)